# tryCatch error "Object not found" in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, try-catch

I am aggregating data from multiple .txt files that fit a specific range. Some of the txt files do not contain the target values which throws an error. (mysteriously, this worked previously and the script would continue - now it throws an error `Error in data.frame(df, f) :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0,` so I introduced tryCatch to write data in data to the missing df.

Using tryCatch to write zeros into the temporary table so it can later be counted. The output file is a new df containing the filtered values and the file it was found.

```
#finds the files with the correct extensions
fs <-list.files(path, pattern=glob2rx("*.txt$")) 
for (f in fs){
  fname <- file.path(path, f)
  df <- read_tsv(fname, skip =1,skip_empty_rows = T, col_types="dd", col_names=c("X1","X2"))
  
  #filters the data that finds the target peak within the tolerances
  # simple 2 column with rows of filtered data
  df<- filter(df,between(X1,mmneg,mmpos))
  
  #create new data based on filtered content
  #tryCatch writes in zeros if no data found.. or it doesn't!
  tryCatch(
    allSpectra <- data.frame(df,f),
    error =function(e) {
      df2<- rbind(df, list(0,0))
      allSpectra <- data.frame(df2,f)
      }
    )
  
  
  #write new data to file
  write.table(allSpectra,
              paste("SearchResults_",mc,"_masstol",tol,"mmu.csv", sep =""),
              append= T,
              sep=",",
              row = F,
              col.names = F
  )
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
> Error: object 'allSpectra' not found
```

When I run the following not inside the for(f in fs) the allSpectra doesn't have an issue. I suspect an error in my tryCatch

```
df2<- rbind(df, list(0,0))
      allSpectra <- data.frame(df2,f)

> allSpectra
  X0 X0.1                                        f
1  0    0 PterocarpusTinctorius_WD161955_Tw313.txt
```

Comment: I would also be happy if it just continued looping to next file and created an empty table

Comment: I think you're using `dplyr` (due to `between`), which means that `filter` is likely returning a `data.frame`, which you then assign within *another* `data.frame`. What do you *think* `df` should be at that point? It'll be much easier to help if the question were reproducible, including representative sample data (such as from `dput(head(x))`).

Comment: @r2evans I have `conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr")` I will clue in what you said, clean it up, and work through. The `df` is a temporary `data.frame` that holds the filtered row from txt `f`. before being combined into the `write.table`

Comment: Yes, what should `data.frame(data.frame(...), data.frame(...))` look like?

Comment: Thank you, posting update below as an answer.  removed the messy second df in a df and adjusted the tryCatch

Answer (score 0):

Removed the unnecessary extra `data.frame` call and allSpectra. Adjusted the `tryCatch` command with a call for `next` f in fs outside the `tryCatch` function.

````
fs <-list.files(path, pattern=glob2rx("*.txt$")) 
for (f in fs){
  fname <- file.path(path, f)
  df <- read_tsv(fname, 
                 skip =1,
                 skip_empty_rows = T, 
                 col_types = "dd",
                 col_names=c("X1","X2")
                 )
  #filters the data that finds the target peak within the tolerances
  #simple 2 column with rows of filtered data
  df<- filter(df,between(X1,mmneg,mmpos)) 
 
  #add filename f to filtered content
  #trycatch skips to next f if no value is present in current f
  skip_to_next <- FALSE
  tryCatch(
    df2<-cbind(df,f),
    error = function (e) { skip_to_next <<- TRUE})
  if(skip_to_next) { next }     
  
  tol2<- tol*1000
  #write new data to file
  write.table(df2,
              paste(species,"_",mc,"_masstol",tol2,"mmu.csv", sep =""),
              append= T,
              sep=",",
              row = F,
              col.names = F
  )
}```
````